# Copy and rename files using a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, shutil

I am relatively new user of python so struggling with the below. Essentially I am trying to move a bunch of files from one folder to other, and rename them using a pandas df I built - states_mapping_df. I tried to convert the df to string using `states_mapping_df = states_mapping_df.astype("string")` but that didnt help.

```
from shutil import copyfile
covid_src_dir = r"I:\COVID\COVID tracker\UserA\Hospitalizations"

covid_new_dir = r"I:\COVID\COVID tracker\Hospitalizations_images"

states_mapping_df = pd.DataFrame ({"Abbr" :['CA','FL','IL','NJ','NY','NC','OH','PA','TX','VA'],
                                   "State_Name" :['California','Florida','Illinois','New Jersey','New York','North Caroliina','Ohio','Pennsylvania','Texas','Virginia']})

for row in states_mapping_df['Abbr']:
    #oldname = states_mapping_df['Abbr']+'.png'
    #newname = states_mapping_df['State_Name']+'.png'
    oldpath_covid = covid_src_dir + "\\" + row +'.png'
    newpath_covid = covid_new_dir + "\\" + states_mapping_df['State_Name'].astype('string') +'.png'
    copyfile(oldpath_covid, newpath_covid)
```

I get the below error when I run it

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-260-40e52504bb33> in <module>
     19     oldpath_covid = covid_src_dir + "\\" + row +'.png'
     20     newpath_covid = covid_new_dir + "\\" + states_mapping_df['State_Name'].astype('string') +'.png'
---> 21     copyfile(oldpath_covid, newpath_covid)
     22     #shutil.copy(oldpath_covid, newpath_covid)

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    238     sys.audit("shutil.copyfile", src, dst)
    239 
--> 240     if _samefile(src, dst):
    241         raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))
    242 

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in _samefile(src, dst)
    215     if hasattr(os.path, 'samefile'):
    216         try:
--> 217             return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
    218         except OSError:
    219             return False

~\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in samefile(f1, f2)
     99     """
    100     s1 = os.stat(f1)
--> 101     s2 = os.stat(f2)
    102     return samestat(s1, s2)
    103 

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Series
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is here`states_mapping_df['State_Name']`

The error is telling you you're using a series. You are trying to rename a file as a whole column of values (series) from the DataFrame.

You need to filter the actual value you want.

Try this.

```
for row in states_mapping_df['Abbr']:
    #oldname = states_mapping_df['Abbr']+'.png'
    #newname = states_mapping_df['State_Name']+'.png'
    
    # filter row of df according to present row from abbr
    filt = (df['Abbr']==row)
    # use .loc to isolate the specific cell from the filter and the column name
    row_filtered = df.loc[filt, 'State_Name']
    # a list is returned where first value is the cell value
    state_name = row_filtered.values[0]
    oldpath_covid = covid_src_dir + "\\" + row +'.png'
    # renamed the initial series to the state name
    newpath_covid = covid_new_dir + "\\" + 
    state_name +'.png'
    copyfile(oldpath_covid, newpath_covid)
```

Edit, a bit more info:

`.loc` is a means of filtering a Pandas DataFrame. You pass your `df.loc[a,b]` with two parameters `a,b` where a = rows and b = columns.
Generally, most will use this in the same way I did above where they first of all create a filter for use in `a` just like I did.
`(df['state'] == 'California')` would return a list of boolean values (true/false) where only instances of `California` would return True. Then when you pass that through `.loc[]` along with your column name then you return the specific cell (or cells if passing through multiple column names for `b`). Then calling `.values` returns an array of said values.

Another method is `.iloc[]` which works the same way though `i` means `integer`. So if you wanted to return the 10th row and columns 5 through 8 you would use `df.iloc[10,5:8]`

Or if you wanted to return everything you could also do `df.iloc[:,:]` or if you wanted to return all columns where your row values equate to California, using the same filter expression as above, then you could use `df.loc[filt, ::]`

The colon expressions represent index slicing just like you do on a list.

More here:

loc
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

iloc
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Indexing and slicing
https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/

Various other filtering methods including those mentioned
https://towardsdatascience.com/7-different-ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframes-9e139888382a

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you meant. Had to make some other changes but managed to make it work.

Comment: You're welcome. Please click the tick to mark my post as the answer so others can see. Cheers!